# How to group results from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

MySQL is my weak point. I have the following MySQL query on a page of mine. The variables $this_groupMembers and $this_groupInvites are both predetermined strings in the form '1,2,3' etc.:

```
SELECT
    username
FROM
    chat_users
WHERE
    ID IN($this_groupMembers) OR
    ID IN($this_groupInvites)
```

What I need to be able to do is to group the results so that I can access the existing members separately from the invited members. I.e. Create the variables $groupMembers_usernames and $groupInvites_usernames from the results of the MySQL query without having to dissect the results with PHP.

Is there a way to do this so that MySQL does all the work?

Thanks you,
Joe

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't run two distinct queries, one for each set of members?

Comment: You can always do two queries if you don't want to dissect the results in PHP...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a UNION with constants to classify the returned rows:

```
SELECT
    username, 'member'
FROM
    chat_users
WHERE
    ID IN($this_groupMembers)
UNION
SELECT
    username, 'invitee'
FROM
    chat_users
WHERE
    ID IN($this_groupInvites)
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting your answer. I fractured my thumb the night I asked this question and I have been out of action since. Better late than never though!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to have two separate queries, however, if -for whatever reason- you really need one you can:

```
SELECT
    username, ID IN($this_groupMembers) AS member
FROM
    chat_users
WHERE
    ID IN($this_groupMembers) OR
    ID IN($this_groupInvites)
```

member will be 1 if member, 0 if invited